# Linq query to join 2 lists of objects and get the altered values as list

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 2 lists with below structure.

```
public class Team
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public Driver Codriver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string DriverId { get; set; }
}

var modifiedTeams = new List<Team>
{
    new Team {Id = "T1", Driver = new Driver { DriverId = "C2" }, Codriver = new Driver { DriverId = "D2"} },
    new Team {Id = "T2", Driver = new Driver { DriverId = "D1"} }
};

var originalTeams = new List<Team>
{
    new Team {Id = "T1", Driver = new Driver { DriverId = "D1" }, Codriver = new Driver { DriverId = "C1"} },
    new Team {Id = "T2", Driver = new Driver { DriverId = "D2"}, Codriver = new Driver { DriverId = "C2"} }
};
```

I want to get a list of all moved team ids along with the member moved. Eg: Team T1 Driver is replaced by Team T2 Codriver. So I want a list as [{T1,Driver},{T2,Codriver}]

> Final Output for above movedTeams is:
>
> ```
> [{T1,"Driver"},{T2, "Codriver"},{T1, "Driver"}]
> ```

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: are you looking for a special linq solution? what have you tried so far?

Comment: @MongZhu I have tried the simple c# solution with for loops but not with LINQ. So wanted to know if this is achievable via LINQ

Comment: I am not sure that I understand it entirely. So you basically compare `modifiedTeams` with `originalTeams` and for each `Team.Id` you check whether the driver, codriver have changed?=! or is even the index important (the position of the team in the list?

Comment: index is not important but I want which team the driver belongs to i.e. Team Id

Answer (score 0):

This will get you want you want, I altered the driver class a bit making LINQ easier.  I'm sure it could be done with less lines but would probably be harder to read. I kept your output format [{T1,"Driver"},{T2, "Codriver"},{T1, "Driver"}], but you should reconsider that and group them together better.

```
    public class Team
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<Driver> Drivers { get; set; }
    }

    public class Driver
    {
        public string DriverId { get; set; }
        public bool IsMainDriver { get; set; }
    }

    public List<string[]> GetDriverMovementList(List<Team> originalTeams, List<Team> modifiedTeams)
    {
        var output = new List<string[]>();
        foreach (var team in modifiedTeams)
        {
            foreach (var driver in team.Drivers)
            {
                // check this team
                var driverOrig = originalTeams.Where(x => x.Id == team.Id).SelectMany(x => x.Drivers).Where(x => x.IsMainDriver != driver.IsMainDriver).FirstOrDefault();
                if (driverOrig == null)
                {
                    // check other teams
                    driverOrig = originalTeams.Where(x => x.Id != team.Id).SelectMany(x => x.Drivers).Where(y => y.DriverId == driver.DriverId).FirstOrDefault();
                }
                if (driverOrig != null)
                {
                    var oldTeam = originalTeams.Where(x => x.Drivers.Contains(driverOrig)).FirstOrDefault();
                    output.Add(new string[] { team.Id, GetDriverRoleName(driver.IsMainDriver) });
                    output.Add(new string[] { oldTeam.Id, GetDriverRoleName(driverOrig.IsMainDriver) });
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }

    public static string GetDriverRoleName(bool isMainDriver)
    {
        if (isMainDriver) { return "Driver"; } else { return "Codriver"; }
    }
```

Comment: You might need the nuget package called MoreLinq for SelectMany.